# ClickOnce package does not install on other computers

Tags: clickonce, dispatcher

I have created a `ClickOnce` package for my application and the Output window in VisualStudio shows that the `ClickOnce` package and .manifest file was created successfully. I tried running it on my machine and it works perfectly.

The problem is the package does not install on some other computers. Whenever I run the package on these computers I get an **error** saying `Application stopped working`. I put a try catch block to the entry point of my application to catch the error message, and the **error** I got is : `Exception Message:Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.`

I thought it might have to do with missing `DLL`s but I have verified that all the needed `DLL`S are copied.

Comment: The error you get doesn't say much. It's more about, that your try-catch is at the wrong place. You can read more about this [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.de/2012/06/systeminvalidoperationexception.html). What type of application do you deploy?

Comment: The application is a .NET application. By the way, after hours and hours of googling, I finally get the application working. What I did was change the Publish Status of some of the application files from 'Pre-requisite' to 'Include'.